# Nested options with argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'd like to have my python script take variable number of arguments depending on a particular choice. For example:

`python run.py foo`

`python run.py bar X Y`

where choosing the option `bar` requires two additional arguments, say integer inputs, but `foo` requires no additional arguments.

```
import argparse

argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# Allow user to choose test to run
argparser.add_argument("test", choices=['foo', 'bar'], help="You may choose foo or bar.")
...
```

But how can I specify additional arguments required by `bar`? P.S. I'm working with Python 2.7, so if a solution requires Python 3, it won't be much help in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use subparsers:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands')

parser_foo = subparsers.add_parser('foo')
parser_foo.set_defaults(target='foo')

parser_bar = subparsers.add_parser('bar')
parser_bar.add_argument('more')
parser_bar.set_defaults(target='bar')
```

Usage:

```
>>> parser.parse_args(['foo'])
Namespace(target='foo')

>>> parser.parse_args(['bar', '123'])
Namespace(target='bar', more='123')
```

---

Note that you could set the `target` to e.g. a function and call it directly. Here's some sample code that does this (extracted from [Cactus' CLI](https://github.com/koenbok/Cactus/blob/3ac6ab309957290cd6ab94a283c75b7d5f59de4b/cactus/cli.py#L66-L114), but that's a rather common pattern):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title = 'subcommands')

parser_create = subparsers.add_parser('create')
parser_create.add_argument('path')
parser_create.add_argument('-s', '--skeleton')
parser_create.set_defaults(target=create)

parser_build = subparsers.add_parser('build')
parser_build.set_defaults(target = build)

args = parser.parse_args()
args.target(**{k: v for k, v in vars(args).items() if k != 'target'})
```